# Lucene query in C# not finding results with punctuation

Tags: c#, search, indexing, lucene

I have a search bar that executes a lucene query on the "description" field, but it doesn't return results when with apostrophes. For example, I have a product where the description is `Herter's® EZ-Load 200lb Feeder - 99018`. When I search for "Herter", I get results, but I get no results if I search for "Herter's" or "Herters". This is my search code:

```
var query = Request.QueryString["q"];
var search = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(query);

var rewardProductLookup = new RewardCatalogDataHelper();
RewardProductSearchCriteria criteria = new RewardProductSearchCriteria()
{
    keywords = search,
    pageSize = 1000,
    sortDirection = "desc"
};

IEnumerable<SkinnyItem> foundProducts = rewardProductLookup.FindByKeywordQuery(criteria);
```

---

```
public IEnumerable<SkinnyItem> FindByKeywordQuery(RewardProductSearchCriteria query)
{
    var luceneIndexDataContext = new LuceneDataContext("rewardproducts", _dbName);
    string fieldToQuery = "rpdescription";
    bool sortDirection = query.sortDirection.ToLower().Equals("desc");

    MultiPhraseQuery multiPhraseQuery = new MultiPhraseQuery();
    var keywords = query.keywords.ToLower().Split(',');
    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            var term = new Term(fieldToQuery, keyword);
            multiPhraseQuery.Add(term);
        }
    }

    var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    booleanQuery.Add(multiPhraseQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    return
        luceneIndexDataContext.BooleanQuerySearch(booleanQuery, fieldToQuery, sortDirection)
            .Where(i => i.Fields["eligibleforpurchase"] == "1");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is analysis.  You haven't specified the analyzer being used in this case, so I'll assume it's `StandardAnalyzer`.

When analyzed, the term "Herter's" will be translated to "herter".  However, no analyzer is being applied in your `FindByKeywordQuery` method, so looking for "herter" works, but "herter's" doesn't.

One solution would be to use the `QueryParser`, in stead of manually constructing a `MultiPhraseQuery`. The QueryParser will handle tokenizing, lowercasing, and such.  Something like:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(VERSION, "text", new StandardAnalyzer(VERSION));
Query query = parser.Parse("\"" + query.keywords + "\"");
```

Comment: What do I put in VERSION?

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to run the Query on my index.

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert Whatever member of the [Version enum](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d3f/namespace_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_util.html#a92602ef4dd5a04278f4b62379d552c0b) you are using in your application. Probably LUCENE_30. As far as running it, just like you would any other lucene query.  Wrap it in your boolean query, or just run it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote is the delimiter for text fields in a query.

```
Select * FROM Product where Description = 'foo'
```

You will need to escape or double any single quote your query. try this in the loop.

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        var term = new Term(fieldToQuery, keyword);
        term = term.Replace("'", "''");
        multiPhraseQuery.Add(term);
    }
}
```

You could also create an extension method

```
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static string SanitizeSQL(this string value)
    {
        return value.Replace("'", "''").Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    }
```

in which case you could then you could do this in the loop

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        var term = new Term(fieldToQuery, keyword.SanitizeSQL());
        multiPhraseQuery.Add(term);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.